# Why getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString(key, value) returns localized string?

Tags: android, android-preferences

I'm working with an application in Android and I have a list preference. The problem is that when I get the value with `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString(key, value)` it returns the localized string instead of the entry value wich is what I'm expecting. In a previous version it was working. That is the right behavior? In that case, how shall i do to get the entry value? Here is some code to explain.

Thanks in advance.

**Preferences.xml:**

```
<ListPreference
android:id="@+id/protocol"
android:key="protocol"
android:title="@string/protocol"
android:dialogTitle="@string/change_protocol"
android:defaultValue="default"
android:entries="@array/protocol_entries"
android:entryValues="@array/protocol_entry_values" />
```

**arrays.xml**

```
<string-array
    name="protocol_entry_values">
    <item>default</item>
    <item>protocol_1</item>
    <item>protocol_2</item>
    <item></item>
</string-array>
<string-array
    name="protocol_entries">
    <item>@string/label_default_protocol</item>
    <item>@string/label_protocol_1</item>
    <item>@string/label_protocol_2</item>
    <item>@string/label_other</item>
</string-array>
```

**strings.xml**

```
<string name="label_default_protocol">Default protocol</string>
<string name="label_protocol_1">First protocol</string>
<string name="label_protocol_2">Second Protocol</string>
<string name="label_other">Other</string>
```

Comment: do you have a localized strings file?

Comment: @toadzky yes I have several strings.xml files with the translated strings. I tested in different languages and it returns the translated string.

Comment: In the `getString` method, the second argument is not the value: it's the default value in case the SharedPreferences do not contain the requested key.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have different versions of the `<string-array name="protocol_entry_values">` data in localized form. You should only have one definition of the values. The `protocol_entries` should be localized.

Comment: Indeed I had several arrays.xml files with the same code but I deleted and it still the same.

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild and see if that helps. Which localized strings do you get back? Is it the ones that you have deleted?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did it and didn't work. It returns the string in the current language of the phone. If I set the phone in Spanish it returns "Primer protocolo". I really don't understand what is happening. It's supposed to work that way and return the correct entry value.

Comment: But in which array is the string that you get back defined? protocol_entry_values, or protocol_entries?

Comment: Now I have only one in res/values/arrays.xml

Comment: The localized strings are in the several string.xml files like res/values/strings.xml (english) or res/values-es/strings.xml (spanish)

Comment: And does the only arrays.xml still look like the one you posted? You don't refer to other resources in the `protocol_entry_values`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18504/discussion-between-tobias-ritzau-and-alejandro-de-gregorio)